# The jade file loading another jade file too many times when rendered by express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have a page.jade including other ones like below:

page.jade

`extend layout.jade`

layout.jade

`include menu.jade`

menu.jade

`- console.log("code from menu.jade")`

And when my app renders the `page.jade`, the console shows the msg three times, which should mean that the menu.jade was executed three times. I pass variables when rendering the `page.jade`, which are also used in `menu.jade`, so the error happens when the `menu.jade` was executed second times and the third times. How can I fix this ?

Thanks for helping